# Why this code is wrong? It provides the wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
  for index in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2) - 1- index]:
      return False
    else: 
      return True
```

It should copmare first element of the lst1 and the last element of lst2. When I run with next comands:

```
print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]))
print(reversed_list([1, 5, 3], [3, 2, 1]))
```

It returns True, however second time should be False

Comment: Please make your title match the question, as is it is useless

Comment: That logic doesn't feel right. Instead: `if lst1[index] != lst2[-(index+1)]:`

Comment: @Dexygen, sorry, I am new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` [immediately stops execution of the function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return#grammar-token-python-grammar-return_stmt), so your function only tests whether the first element of `lst1` is equal to the last element of `lst2`. This is the correct thing to do if they don't match, but if they *do* match, you should continue your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
    for index in range(len(lst1)):
        if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2) - 1- index]:
              return False
    return True
```